# Apply RandomReal to list in list in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, random

I have a big list: `{{1,1,1},{1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}....{1,1,1,1}}`
How can I apply `RandomReal` to every single element in the list?

Comment: Its it just a list of lists of 1's?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to "apply" `RandomReal` to a $1$.  Do you instead want a list of lists having the same lengths as your "big list" whose elements are `RandomReal`'s?

Comment: Maybe `data = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
RandomReal[1, Length[#]] & /@ data`.

Comment: Remember to always provide clear description or examples. What you ask for (apply RandomReal to elements) is `RandomReal @@ 1`, do you really want that?

Comment: Sorry, I did not make question clear. I was trying to change all 1 in list to RandomReal.

Answer (score 5):

```
lst = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
```

[`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html):

```
Map[RandomReal[] &, lst, {-1}]
```

> {{0.889429, 0.591787, 0.501054}, {0.798018, 0.450399}, {0.203298, 
>     0.516828, 0.915914, 0.382806, 0.556068, 0.989846, 
>     0.506031}, {0.888463, 0.320624, 0.598728, 0.966887}}

[`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
lst /. 1 :> RandomReal[]
```

> {{0.278371, 0.00602005, 0.359501}, {0.914092, 0.000602509}, {0.526115,
>      0.445291, 0.18624, 0.771961, 0.41898, 0.497914, 
>     0.245191}, {0.84795, 0.188699, 0.93049, 0.129465}}

Also:

```
With[{l = Length /@ lst}, RandomReal[1, #] & /@ l] 
With[{l = Length /@ lst}, Internal`PartitionRagged[RandomReal[1, Total[l]], l]]
```

Comment: The last solution is quite elegant (+1).

Comment: Thank you @David.

Comment: Thank you!  but I do not understand how to use RandomReal[]&, what is & for?

Comment: It is a pure function (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html), similar to anonymous or lambda functions in other languages.